# Bootstrap layout on smaller screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, cordova

I'm using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) to build webpages into applications which are created using [Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) and [Flat UI](http://designmodo.com/demo/flat-ui/). Everything seems to be working fine but I am having one issue. When I test the webpage on my desktop or laptop the layout is fine, divided in the 12 sections, but when I attempt to have either images or buttons on the same row on the phone layout, they are placed vertically on top of the other.

For example, if I have two buttons on one row, both buttons will be stretched to the width of the phone and placed on two separate rows.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href=".\back.html" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-success">BACK</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <a href=".\next.html" class="btn btn-block btn-lg btn-inverse">NEXT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Also, at the top I have declared:

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any idea's as to why this is happening?

One thing I wanted to do was have 6 boxes numbered 1-6 that the user could select from. I wanted to have 2 numbers per row and to have 3 rows. When I tried to implement the images (numbered boxes) in this way, they were stretched again and there ended up being 6 rows and massive boxes.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `.col-md-6`, which is for medium size screens. If you wish to have them placed the same way on phones (x-small devices), you need to use `.col-xs-6` instead.

For further information, you can read the [bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed) on how to set that up.

Comment: Thanks this was the issue. I remember seeing lines with "<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 col-md-4">" and being very confused because at some point I remember reading that they all perform the same action and I just left it at that. Note to self: don't believe everything you read on the internet. ^_^ Thanks again.

Comment: @BASmith Well, they do the same thing, but for different resolutions. When you set one of those, they will only show like that **starting at** the screen size you selected. So if you do `.col-md`, it will display on medium and up, if you select `.col-sm`, it will be on small and up. So if you want to set 2 columns for phones, but 3 on the rest, you would do `.col-xs-6 .col-sm-4`. If you set only `.col-md`, you will get that column distribution on `.col-md` and up, anything lower will display as full width (or `.col-xs-12`)

Answer (score 0):

In old bootstrap 2.3.2 grid syntax look like this

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">left</div>
        <div class="span6">right</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

class="row-fluid" used when we want to get a responsive design, but in this case all (.col-md-6 - in new bootstrap or .span6 in old bootstrap) element display as block element with width=100%
Look [at old 2.3.2 bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#gridSystem) grid in developers tools an re-size window width.
And look at this [new 3 bootstrap grid](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed) in developers tools an re-size window width.
Сompare and understand everything.